# retrieving audit history using Z.EntityFramework.Plus.AuditExtensions.Where in DB first?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-plus

I'm using Z.EntityFramework.Plus package to implement the audit feature in my project;
I'm following the DB first approach, I run the query that created the two audit tables as described [here](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus/wiki/EF-Audit-%7C-Entity-Framework-Audit-Trail-Context-and-Track-Changes#autosave-audit): 
by updating the .edmx file I got those new DBsets

```
public virtual DbSet<AuditEntries> AuditEntries { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<AuditEntryProperties> AuditEntryProperties { get; set; }
```

now I want to retrieve the audit history, I use `Where` extension method in Z.EntityFramework.Plus namespace:

```
var auditlog = AuditExtensions.Where<TbAdditions>(oContext.AuditEntries, id).ToList();
```

but the compiler is yelling out at me, that he can't cast the `DBset<AuditEntry>` to `DBSet<AuditEntries>` as in the `Where` definition it requires `DbSet<AuditEntry>`, not `DbSet<AuditEntries>`, should I change the name of the table?

Comment: What is `AuditEntries` here then? Surely that should be `AuditEntry`?

Comment: there is a class named `AuditEntry` built-in the package itself , I'm confused between it and the created table `AuditEntries`

Comment: Then use `AuditEntry`, don't create your own.

Comment: It's not a code class it's the mapped entity from the database that holds the audit history

Comment: It's still a code class, even if it's a mapped entity. Tell your DB first to use the correct entity in the EDMX config I guess?

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Plus](http://entityframework-plus.net/)

You are currently using DB first approach with custom class `AuditEntries` and `AuditEntryProperties`. So you are not using Code First with class `AuditEntry` and `AuditEntryProperty` provided by Z.EntityFramework.Plus library.

The extension method has been made for the class provided by the library, so that's why it's incompatible with your class.

You will have to implement on your side the same extension methods found on this source: [DbSet`AuditEntry.cs](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus/blob/master/src/Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EF6/Audit/Extensions/DbSet%60AuditEntry/DbSet%60AuditEntry.cs)

Probably more extension methods will be required.

The Audit feature is supposed to be fully re-coded during the summer to allow more extensibility like this feature.

**EDIT: Answer sub-question**

> How to implement it?

Here is an example how to implement it: https://gist.github.com/mshwf/af017b50ceb2994d953762ef2b20386d

Comment: Do you mean `GetContext()` by `GetDbContext()`? and what is `GetKeyNames<T>`, how to implement it, is it something like this https://romiller.com/2014/10/07/ef6-1-getting-key-properties-for-an-entity/?